# Error in the connection of SoapUI with Cassandra

Tags: jdbc, groovy, cassandra, soapui

I am trying to connect the SoapUI with Cassandra database. The database is in a server and I need to access using user and password. I tested the connection in Datastax and it works.

I have researched, and I added these jars:
 [Jars used to connect Cassandra with SoapUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ffjM.jpg)
I prefer to connect using JDBC step, but I am trying using groovy script too.

***JDBC Request***
Information used for the connection:

Driver: org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDrive
Connection String: jdbc:cassandra://user:password@ip-address:9042/tracking_system

**Error:** com.eviware.soapui.support.SoapUIException: Failed to init connection for driver [org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDrive], connectionString

***Groovy Script***
I tried to connect also using the groovy script

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.*;
import com.dbschema.CassandraJdbcDriver.*;

com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDrive");
def con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://user:password@ip-address:9160/tracking_system");
```

Groovy code complete
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNBXK.jpg)

**Error:**
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:cassandra://

Comment: you need to add the driver to your classpath (for groovy)

Comment: can you show the code before you did the groovy script?

Comment: I added the code complete, I do not know if I am missing something.

Comment: The error means that it can't find the driver. I don't know about groovy but I suppose it works like java, so did you add the driver to the classpath?

Comment: Thanks, I added this line: com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");

Comment: Now I got this error: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection url may only include host, port, and keyspace, consistency and version option, e.g., jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9170/Keyspace1?version=3.0.0&consistency=ONE. I will check the jar version, could it be the problem?

Comment: Try using the keyspace name instead of the user name and password.http://abhishekasthana.com/accessing-cassendra-soapui/